# WPF ComboBox bound to enum collection, difference between .net 4 and 4.5

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I had interesting issue with WPF combobox, where ItemSource was bound to CollectionViewSource based on collection of enums and SelectedItem was bound to enum property. Problem I had was that in .net 4.0, when nothing was selected yet, combobox had red border indicating validation error or exception. I think it was happening because SelectedIndex was still -1, so SelectedItem was still null, and this value could not be assigned to enum property, since it is not nullable. Error message was saying something along lines "Value '' cannot be converted".

In .net 4.5 however this problem is gone. Why? Do you know of something got changed in Combobox/Binding that fixed it? Is WPF source available so I can check it? Have you seen same behavior / change?

Thanks

Comment: maybe Binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors is some how set to false ?  

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesondataerrors(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: post your an example to what your Binding to ..

Comment: It was same code in both .net 4 and 4.5. Problem with example is that I have .net 4.5 on my machine, and no VM with .net 4 only at hand :)

Comment: still post what you are binding to.. maybe you miss read the issue causing the DataError